How do I implement functions that operate on `UnionM [UnionM SymInteger]`?
This is about the Grisette library.
Let me first explain my understanding of why we need this monstrosity. Essentially, I want to work on lists of SymInteger. But, AFAIU, you need to wrap a SymInteger into a UnionM whenever the result of an operation is not a simple value (like 2 or "a") and it is e.g., a condition (e.g., the result of mrgIf).
Now, suppose we want to create a function that takes two [SymInteger] and returns a [SymInteger] that has the element-wise maximum of the two lists. We cannot do the following:
pickLargest :: [SymInteger] -> [SymInteger] -> [SymInteger]
-- skip simple cases
pickLargest (x:xs) (y:ys) = (mrgIf (x .> y) x y) : (sumSym xs ys)

because mrgIf returns UnionM SymInteger and not SymInteger. So, we need [UnionM SymInteger] for our functions to be generic, like so:
pickLargest :: [UnionM SymInteger] -> [UnionM SymInteger] -> [UnionM SymInteger]
-- ...
pickLargest (x:xs) (y:ys) = (mrgIf (x .> y) x y) : (pickLargest xs ys)

Now, suppose that I also want to create a function that drops an element from a list, if it exists. I can't use symDrop because that takes a SymInteger and not a UnionM SymInteger.  So, the following won't work:
myVar :: [UnionM SymInteger]
myVar = pickLargest ["a", "b"] ["c", "d"]

dropOnSym = print (symDrop (head myVar) myVar)

Note: Using head myVar is just a simple choice of an element that for sure exists. Ideally, I want a function that drops an element from a [SymInteger], that may or may not exist.
because head myVar has type UnionM SymInteger (and AFAIU, it will also not work
if I want to call symDrop on the result of symDrop). Finally, because we don't know the length of the resulting list, it makes sense that it needs to be wrapped in a UnionM.
Thus, the only way to implement symListDrop I've found is this:
symListDrop :: UnionM [UnionM SymInteger] -> UnionM SymInteger -> UnionM [UnionM SymInteger]
symListDrop m_ls el = do
  ls <- m_ls
  case ls of
    [] -> mrgReturn []
    (x:xs) -> mrgIf (x .== el)
                (symListDrop (mrgReturn xs) el)
                (do
                  res <- (symListDrop (mrgReturn xs) el)
                  (mrgReturn (x:res)))

which I'm afraid is just me trying really really hard... In particular, the fact that I have to unpack the UnionM seems suspicious.
So, do you have a suggestion on how to implement this function, or alternatively, a different way that these problems are supposed to be modeled?

This seems to be about a specific library. What library?

It's about Grisette (https://github.com/lsrcz/grisette). Sorry, I had it in the title but someone deleted it. I added it in the body.

You'll probably have more luck asking on their issue tracker or sending the authors an email.

@Li-yaoXia maybe, but asking about how functions in libraries isn't off-topic here, even if the library is a bit niche.

Edit after receiving the comments
After receiving the comments I think that what you want is a deleteFirst function, like the one discussed in this SO answer.
To make it symbolic, you don't have to wrap the arguments of the function in UnionM, instead, what you need is just wrapping the result with it.
symDeleteFirst :: [SymInteger] -> SymInteger -> UnionM [SymInteger]
symDeleteFirst [] _ = mrgReturn []
symDeleteFirst (x:xs) v = mrgIf (x .== v) (mrgReturn xs) (mrgFmap (x:) $ symDeleteFirst xs v)

This function can still be used on UnionM [SymInteger], as follows:
a :: UnionM [SymInteger]
a = mrgIf "x" (return ["a", "b"]) (return ["c", "d", "e"])

n :: SymInteger
n = "n"

do
  v <- a
  symDeleteFirst v n

The result will be as follows. It's a bit complicated, although it is likely to be one of the simplest results, as there are many branches in the program.
{If (&& x (|| (= a n) (= b n)))
  [(ite (= a n) b a)]
  (If (|| x (|| (= c n) (|| (= d n) (= e n))))
    [(ite x a (ite (= c n) d c)),(ite x b (ite (|| (= c n) (= d n)) e d))]
    [c,d,e])
}

For the minimum function mentioned in the comment, there is a symMinimum function that works on [SymInteger].
To use it on UnionM [SymInteger], you can use fmap to get a UnionM SymInteger result, and then merge the UnionM SymInteger into SymInteger using simpleMerge:
a :: UnionM [SymInteger]
a = mrgIf "x" (return ["a", "b"]) (return ["c", "d", "e"])

simpleMerge $ symMinimum <$> a

This will give you
(ite x (ite (<= b a) b a) (ite (<= e (ite (<= d c) d c)) e (ite (<= d c) d c)))

First version
Thanks for your interest in the Grisette library, and I am the author of it. I have just set up the GitHub discussions, so further discussions can go there.
TL;DR
If you haven't check it out, a small tutorial has been built for Grisette recently.
You don't have to use UnionM SymInteger in most cases, and your pickLargest can be implemented using mrgIte.
pickLargest :: [SymInteger] -> [SymInteger] -> [SymInteger]
-- skip simple cases
pickLargest (x:xs) (y:ys) = (mrgIte (x .> y) x y) : (sumSym xs ys)

symDrop isn't what you need. You may want to upgrade to latest Grisette and use mrgDelete. symMax is also available there.
With symMax an even simpler solution exists:
pickLargest :: [SymInteger] -> [SymInteger] -> [SymInteger]
pickLargest = zipWith symMax

Your symListDrop is calling itself with the same operands, and this is why it recurses infinitely.
Before the discussion on SymInteger
I have a first question for you, which is, is the symDrop the function you want? Its semantics is like the drop in base, where the second SymInteger is the number of elements to drop from the head of the list, not the element to drop.
I suggest that you upgrade to the latest Grisette package (v0.5.0.1 as of today), which is available on Hackage or Stackage nightly snapshots. Almost all functions from Data.List have a symbolic version there, and the mrgDelete function may be what you want. Please expect some incompatibilities between the versions as some functions are renamed with a more consistent naming scheme, e.g., symDrop has been renamed to mrgDrop because it returns a union. (Estimated) complexities for the operators are also available in the documentation.
SimpleMergeable and mrgIte
The UnionM container is introduced to handle multi-path execution for complex data structures. These data structures do not have the abilities to handle the path conditions by themselves, so we store them in multiple branches in the UnionM container.
However, some data structures, e.g., symbolic primitive types (SymBool, SymInteger, etc.), tuple of symbolic primitive types ((SymBool, SymInteger)), have the ability to hold the path conditions by themselves. These data structures implements the SimpleMergeable type class, which provides the mrgIte function.
mrgIte :: (SimpleMergeable a) => SymBool -> a -> a -> a

It may be confusing at the first sight, because we have two distinct versions for "splitting paths", but this is actually intentional, and mrgIf and mrgIte have different semantics. The mrgIf is analogous to a control flow structure, e.g., if statement in C, while the mrgIte is a ternary operator for building an expression, e.g., ?: in C.
If you do need to work with UnionM SymInteger...
Sometimes the use of a UnionM of simply mergeable types cannot be avoided, for example, when you have a generic data structure which uses UnionM internally. Grisette provides helpers to work with them (e.g., (.#), and onUnion), and the type signature is as follows:
onUnion :: (SimpleMergeable r, Mergeable a) => (a -> r) -> UnionM a -> r

For the infinite recursion
Your function is calling itself (symListDrop m_ls m_el) with exactly the same operands in the last line.
An implementation for your original question

Now, suppose we want to create a function that takes two [SymInteger] and returns a [SymInteger] that has the element-wise maximum of the two lists.

This can be implemented using zipWith and symMax with the latest Grisette:
pickLargest :: [SymInteger] -> [SymInteger] -> [SymInteger]
pickLargest = zipWith symMax


Hi Sirui, thanks! Well, I guess I was fighting the type system too much to figure out the obvious infinite recursion. I'll update the post. In short, ideally I need a function that drops an element from a list that may or may not exist. Using the result of head above was a simple option of an element that for sure exists. I have added an updated implementation that doesn't go infinite, but it still seems wrong, again because I have to unpack the monad. Finally, AFAIU, you can't avoid returning a UnionM [SymInteger], which forces the rest of the system to work with UnionM [SymInteger].

Btw, if you actually do need to work with UnionM [SymInteger], then I can't figure out how to even do a simple function that finds the min of a UnionM [SymInteger] such that it returns a SymInteger and not a Union SymInteger.

Let me read your updates. Before that, for working with UnionM SymInteger, another useful function is the simpleMerge function. It merges a UnionM of simply mergeable type to a single value.

Also, another tip for writing code with Grisette is that you usually only need to wrap the result, but not the arguments of a function in the UnionM or other monad. Doing this unpacking at the call site usually gives you easier-reading code.
This means, symListDrop :: [SymInteger] -> SymInteger -> UnionM [SymInteger] is a better choice in my opinion.

Thanks for all the answers again! I learned enough to figure out how the library should work. The last comment makes a lot of sense. I was thinking that if you need UnionM [SymInteger] somewhere, then the whole library needs to operate on that. But you can just return that and unpack it, as you said. Here's a drop on a drop for example:
firstDrop = series_drop_first mySymList (head mySymList)
dropOnDrop :: UnionM [SymInteger]
dropOnDrop = do
unpk <- firstDrop
series_drop_first unpk (head unpk)
